# Kivy: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've been trying to fix this error that gives me when I try to add a widget to the class that inherit Gridlayout, I dont really know if the class that inherit widget is the issue or the gridlayout one, I've been trying to do many things wihout any result so I want to ask if this has a solution

the first class is the class that inherit widget

```
class MyPaintElement(Widget):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyPaintElement, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.active = False

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    # Check if touch event is inside widget
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        self._draw_rectange()

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    # Check if touch event is inside widget
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        # If so, draw rectangle
        self._draw_rectange()

def _draw_rectange(self):
    self.canvas.clear()
    with self.canvas:
        # lets draw a semi-transparent red square
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1, mode='rgba')
        Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width*0.9, self.height*0.9))
    self.active = True

def clear(self, color):
    self.canvas.clear()
    with self.canvas:
        if color == "black":
            # lets draw a semi-transparent red square
            Color(0, 0.65, 0.65, 1, mode='rgba')
        else:
            Color(0, 0.2, 0.2, 1, mode='rgba')
        Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width*0.9, self.height*0.9))
    self.active = False

def mark(self):
    self._draw_rectange()
```

the second one class is where i call this one to instance in the "add_widget" part is the one that inherit GridLayout

```
class MyPaintWidget(GridLayout):

CODING_SIZE = 4

def __init__(self, size, **kwargs):
    super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = size
    for index in range(self.cols * self.cols):
        self.add_widget(MyPaintElement())

def clear(self):
    index = 0
    #with self.canvas.before:
    #    Color(0, .1, .3, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
    #    self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size,
    #                         pos=self.pos)

    for child in self.children:
        if index % 2:
            child.clear("dark-turquoise")
        else:
            child.clear("black")
        index += 1

def get_pattern(self):
    # Initial pattern is an empty list of integers
    pattern = []
    # Integer representation or first row of pattern (bottom)
    val = 0
    # Counter to obtain integer value from binary row
    count = 1
    # For each MyPaintElement instance, verify if active and
    # add integer value to val depending on its position (count)
    for child in self.children:
        if child.active:
            val += count
        count *= 2
        # If row over, append to pattern array and
        # start encoding new one
        if count == pow(2, MyPaintWidget.CODING_SIZE):
            pattern.append(val)
            val = 0
            count = 1
    return pattern

def draw_pattern(self, pattern):
    """ Draw given pattern in painter"""
    for index in range(len(pattern)):
        # Get children in groups of four (As codification was made by groups of four)
        child_offset = index*MyPaintWidget.CODING_SIZE
        child_set = self.children[child_offset:child_offset+MyPaintWidget.CODING_SIZE]
        # Convert current number of pattern into binary
        format_str = "{0:0"+str(MyPaintWidget.CODING_SIZE)+"b}"
        bin_pattern_element = format_str.format(pattern[index])
        # Traverse binary, mark or clear corresponding child
        for j in range(len(bin_pattern_element)):
            if bin_pattern_element[MyPaintWidget.CODING_SIZE-1-j] == "1":
                child_set[j].mark()
            else:
                if j % 2:
                    child_set[j].clear("dark-turquoise")
                else:
                    child_set[j].clear("black")
```

so finally, The error that it gives me is this

```
File ".\main.py", line 513, in <module>
MyPaintApp().run()
File "C:\PATH\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
root = self.build()
File ".\main.py", line 509, in build
intentions_ui = IntentionsInterface()
File ".\main.py", line 244, in __init__
self.add_widgets_layouts()
File ".\main.py", line 364, in add_widgets_layouts
self.desired_state_panel = GridLayout(cols=1, padding_x = 10, size_hint_y = 1,size_hint_x=0.5)
File "C:\PATH\site-packages\kivy\uix\gridlayout.py", line 256, in __init__
super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "C:\PATH\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "C:\PATH\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

so, I want to know why this is happening, I would really appreciate any advice or recommendation !

Answer (score 0):

I think the columns of the Grid layout is not initialized.

```
super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

needs to be modified to

```
super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(size)
```

Comment: Hi !, I tried this but it throws me this error,  `super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(size)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution, but i tried "calling" the app differently, and it worked. Try this:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

#this is what i call "calling":
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```